# Data is not updated when reloading the page after an API call

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In my VueJS application I make an API call to get user statistics that I want to present to the user. It is rather simple with Java backend and an `$axios` get request. When I just run the app the first time and view the page, it is all working as expected, but when updating the page or going to some other page and going back, the values are instead 0.

I guess it is because the DOM for whatever reason is not updated, but if I open the development tools and look in the "Network" section, I can see that the API call is being made and that I do get the data, it is just not displayed

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Users:</h3>
    <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
      <v-row
        v-for="(d, index) in data"
        :key="index"
        no-gutters
      >
        <v-col>
          <v-card
            class="pa-2"
            outlined
            tile
          >
            {{ d.title }}
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-card
            class="pa-2"
            outlined
            tile>
            {{ d.value }}
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {Component, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
  created() {
    this.$accessor.users.loadNumOfNewUsers()
  },
  mounted() {
    this.newUsers()
  }
})
export default class ShowNewUsers extends Vue {
  data = [
    { title: "New users:", value: -1 },
  ]

  newUsers() {
    Vue.set(this.data[0], "value", this.$accessor.users.newUsers);
  }
}
</script>
```

The API calls (like `this.$accessor.users.loadNumOfNewUsers()` and `this.$accessor.users.newUsers`) are made from an API call to my Java backend, in this case it looks like this, and as I stated seems to work just fine

```
import {actionTree, getterTree, mutationTree} from "typed-vuex";

export const state = () => ({
  newUsers: 0,
});

export type AdminState = ReturnType<typeof state>;

export const getters = getterTree(state, {
  newUsers: (state: AdminState) => state.newUsers,
});

export const mutations = mutationTree(state, {
  setNumOfNewUsers(state: AdminState, numOfNewUsers) {
    state.newUsers = newUsers
  }
});

export const actions = actionTree(
  {state, getters, mutations},
  {
    async loadNumOfNewUsers({commit}) {
      const numOfNewUsersUrl = '/api/my/java/backend'
      await this.$axios.get(numOfNewUsersUrl).then((response) => {
        commit('setNumOfNewUsers', response.data)
      })
    },
  },
);
```

Is it that I have to use the `@Watch` decorator maybe? But the way I understand it is that is only needed if I want changes to be responsive, it should still work to just reload the page. Also it is strange that I get 0 as the value instead of -1 (which is its base value). This probably mean that there is some yanky JavaScript converson from NaN perhaps, but honestly have no ideea.

Comment: It will be great if you share more of your code. loadNumOfNewUsers for example. I am also wondering, if you call an API to get newUsers number how come it works the first time ? I mean the call must be async but you have nothing to indicates that and wait for the response before calling newUsers()

Comment: @walox Sorry added also how I do the API calls. But like I said that part seems to be working just fine, hence the reason I did not include it

Comment: loadNumOfNewUsers is async. the created function is sync so when mounted is first run the data won't be available yet. I don't understand how this is working even the first time.

Comment: @walox Me neither, this particular problem have had me doing some quite scetchy stuff that I am not familiar with at all, but trying something new atm and will get back with how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this that however do not include TypeScript is to create `computed` and `watch` modules where `computed` look at when fetching the value and also update it when it changes and then actually updating `items` data variable with the `watch` module waiting for this to happen and then updating the variable to present.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NewUsers",
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      {text: 'What', value: 'what'},
      {text: 'Number', value: 'num'}
    ],
    items: []
  }),
  computed: {
    getNewUsers() {
      return this.$accessor.admin.newUsers
    }
  },
  watch: {
    getData() {
      this.items.push({what: 'Number of new users', num: this.getNewUsers})
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$accessor.admin.loadNumOfNewUsers()
  },
}
</script>
```